# Set up a dynamic working range in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, dynamic, calculation

So I have a data which is basically a working hours calculation. The excel data consists of Day and time but for some reason the time is doubling in some cells:

[image]

My task is to find the working hours in each day by take the "end time" minus the "begin time" and I intended to do it by using MAX(range)- MIN(range) and loop it for each day.

But I don't know how to define the range that consist data of each day. As you see 01-07 could have 3 rows but 02-07 could have 4 rows of data

Can anyone help me to solve it using VBA?

Comment: It's a trivial task, but for the sake of data quality it might be of interest to correct whatever is causing the data duplication. Would you consider a macro to delete the surplus rows? This would let you use the MIN/MAX approach you describe. Otherwise you'll have to do the summation inside some VBA code.

Comment: Thank you Peh but the duplication is also random. I use Min and Max function as a way to get around it as I takes the earliest time as the begin time and the latest time of the day as the end time. It would be more stressful to remove these duplicates than just to ignore it